# How to use JqueryUI create new tabs with custom content

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I use Jquery UI to create tabs. I want create new tabs with content tab1 = content tab2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of jQuery to accomplish this.  Assuming that your jQuery UI tags code looks like:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Test content</div>
</div>
```

You can use something similar to the following to copy the content into the first tab.

```
var content = $('#tabs-2').html();
$('#tabs-1').html(content);
```

This code takes the HTML string within the tabs-2 div and stores it in a variable.  It then sets the content in tabs-1 div to the variable.